# How to make calendar list events based on priority

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a calendar design in which i would like to list the saved calendar events based on priority in a same listview. I need to differentiate each priority with different colors eg:red-high, yellow-medium and green-low. I have to place all the three priorities in a single list view as below. How to achieve it? Any Help is appreciated and Thanks in advance...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the events saved in the db with the field "priority" you can create a custom CursorAdapter and set the background coulor of each line based on the field priority value.